# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

I am querying from a PostGre db in my Django project.

Below is my code.

```
flight_schedule_detail_instance = FlightScheduleDetail.objects.filter
            schedule_id=FlightSchedule.objects.filter(schedule_id=instance.schedule_id),
            flight_date=str(tomorrow_date)
            )
```

I need to filter all the instances which has a particular `schedule_id` and a `flight_date` . This works in my localhost. I am using sqlite in my localhost code. The server uses PostGre db. How do I query to get my desired results?

Also, `flight_date` in my `FlightScheduleDetail` model is a `DateField`. And my `schedule_id` is a Foriegn key to another model which is a `CharField` in that model.

I also tried without having a `str` wrapper to my `tomorrow_date` variable which is a `date` object.

My `models.py` :

```
class FlightScheduleDetail(models.Model):
    flight_date = models.DateField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    schedule_id = models.ForeignKey(FlightSchedule, null=False, related_name="schedule_details", blank=False)
    route_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    flight_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null=True, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.route_id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "flights Schedule Details"


class FlightSchedule(models.Model):
    tail_number = models.ForeignKey(TailNumber, null=False, blank=False)
    schedule_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    flight_group_code = models.ForeignKey(FlightGroup, null=False, blank=False)
    minLength = MinLengthValidator(limit_value=7)
    binary = RegexValidator(r'^[0-1]*$', 'Only 0s and 1s are allowed.')
    scheduled_days = models.CharField(max_length=7, validators=[binary, minLength], null=True, blank=True,
                                      default="1111111")
    origin_port_code = models.ForeignKey(Port, null=False, related_name="Origin", blank=False)
    destination_port_code = models.ForeignKey(Port, null=False, related_name="Destination", blank=False)
    flight_departure_time = models.TimeField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.schedule_id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "flights Schedule"
```

and I am calculating my `tomorrow_date` as follows :

```
tomorrow_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of why you should use the same database in development and production. Sqlite does not have a concept of types. You can declare field types but they are not strictly followed. So you can easily insert text data into Date fields. Postgresql on the other hand is very strict about types.

Updating my answer based on updates to the question.

I am not quite sure, if you need that elaborate query. You have an instance of a `FlightSchedule` and that instance will give you direct access to all the related `FilightScheduleDetail` instances. you can just filter on it like this

```
instance.flightscheduledetail_set.filter(flight_date=tommorow_date)
```

If you continue to have the error, it can only mean that there is a missig migration somewhere.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question , I did try taking out the `str` cast in my query. And also my `flight_date` is a `DateField` .

Comment: And like I mentioned in my answer, sqlite allows you to put anything into an field. You should post your full models. and also show what tommorow_date looks like

Comment: Still not MCVE please add the FlightSchedule model also

Comment: have added the FlightSchedule also